# Grammaticality of 'is at fault'

Tags: grammaticality

Is it fine to use "is at fault" as follows?

> Very soon I realized that he is at fault.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with using it?

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with *at fault*, but the sentence should read:

> Very soon I realized that he was at fault.